# Optimizing assembly generated by Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, optimization, assembly

I'm working on a project with matrix multiplication. I have been able to write the C code and I was able to generate the assembly code for it using the Microsoft visual studio 2012 compiler. The compiler generated code is shown below. The compiler used the SSE registers, which is exactly what I wanted, but it is not the best code. I wanted to optimize this code and write it inline with the C code but I don't understand the assembly code. Basically the assembly code is good for only one dimension of the matrix, the code below is only good for 4 by 4 matrix. How can I make is so that it is good for n*n matrix size.

The C++ code is shown below:

```
#define MAX_NUM 10
#define MAX_DIM 4

int main () {
    float mat_a [] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    float mat_b [] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    float result [] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    int num_row = 4;
    int num_col = 4;

    float sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_row; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < num_col; j++) {
          sum = 0.0;
          for (int k = 0; k < num_row; k++) {
             sum = sum + mat_a[i * num_col + k] * mat_b[k * num_col + j];
          }
          *(result + i * num_col + j) = sum; 
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code is shown below:

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 

    TITLE   C:\Users\GS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assembly_InLine\Assembly_InLine\Source.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB MSVCRTD
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  _main
PUBLIC  __real@00000000
PUBLIC  __real@3f800000
PUBLIC  __real@40000000
PUBLIC  __real@40400000
PUBLIC  __real@40800000
EXTRN   @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8:PROC
EXTRN   @__security_check_cookie@4:PROC
EXTRN   __RTC_InitBase:PROC
EXTRN   __RTC_Shutdown:PROC
EXTRN   ___security_cookie:DWORD
EXTRN   __fltused:DWORD
;   COMDAT __real@40800000
CONST   SEGMENT
__real@40800000 DD 040800000r           ; 4
CONST   ENDS
;   COMDAT __real@40400000
CONST   SEGMENT
__real@40400000 DD 040400000r           ; 3
CONST   ENDS
;   COMDAT __real@40000000
CONST   SEGMENT
__real@40000000 DD 040000000r           ; 2
CONST   ENDS
;   COMDAT __real@3f800000
CONST   SEGMENT
__real@3f800000 DD 03f800000r           ; 1
CONST   ENDS
;   COMDAT __real@00000000
CONST   SEGMENT
__real@00000000 DD 000000000r           ; 0
CONST   ENDS
;   COMDAT rtc$TMZ
rtc$TMZ SEGMENT
__RTC_Shutdown.rtc$TMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_Shutdown
rtc$TMZ ENDS
;   COMDAT rtc$IMZ
rtc$IMZ SEGMENT
__RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ DD FLAT:__RTC_InitBase
rtc$IMZ ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp /RTCsu /ZI
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_k$1 = -288                     ; size = 4
_j$2 = -276                     ; size = 4
_i$3 = -264                     ; size = 4
_sum$ = -252                        ; size = 4
_num_col$ = -240                    ; size = 4
_num_row$ = -228                    ; size = 4
_result$ = -216                     ; size = 64
_mat_b$ = -144                      ; size = 64
_mat_a$ = -72                       ; size = 64
__$ArrayPad$ = -4                   ; size = 4
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT
; File c:\users\gs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\assembly_inline\assembly_inline\source.cpp
; Line 4
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 484                ; 000001e4H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-484]
    mov ecx, 121                ; 00000079H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
    mov eax, DWORD PTR ___security_cookie
    xor eax, ebp
    mov DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp], eax
; Line 5
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+4], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+8], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+12], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+16], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+20], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+24], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+28], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+32], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+36], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+40], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+44], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+48], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+52], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+56], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+60], xmm0
; Line 6
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+4], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+8], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+12], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+16], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+20], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+24], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+28], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+32], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+36], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+40], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+44], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@3f800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+48], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+52], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+56], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40800000
    movss   DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+60], xmm0
; Line 7
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+4], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+8], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+12], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+16], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+20], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+24], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+28], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+32], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+36], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+40], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+44], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+48], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+52], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+56], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+60], xmm0
; Line 9
    mov DWORD PTR _num_row$[ebp], 4
; Line 10
    mov DWORD PTR _num_col$[ebp], 4
; Line 14
    mov DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN9@main
$LN8@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp], eax
$LN9@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _num_row$[ebp]
    jge $LN7@main
; Line 15
    mov DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN6@main
$LN5@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp], eax
$LN6@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _num_col$[ebp]
    jge $LN4@main
; Line 16
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@00000000
    movss   DWORD PTR _sum$[ebp], xmm0
; Line 17
    mov DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN3@main
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp], eax
$LN3@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _num_row$[ebp]
    jge SHORT $LN1@main
; Line 18
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp]
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR _num_col$[ebp]
    add eax, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _k$1[ebp]
    imul    ecx, DWORD PTR _num_col$[ebp]
    add ecx, DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR _mat_a$[ebp+eax*4]
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR _mat_b$[ebp+ecx*4]
    addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR _sum$[ebp]
    movss   DWORD PTR _sum$[ebp], xmm0
; Line 19
    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN1@main:
; Line 20
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$3[ebp]
    imul    eax, DWORD PTR _num_col$[ebp]
    lea ecx, DWORD PTR _result$[ebp+eax*4]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _j$2[ebp]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR _sum$[ebp]
    movss   DWORD PTR [ecx+edx*4], xmm0
; Line 21
    jmp $LN5@main
$LN4@main:
; Line 22
    jmp $LN8@main
$LN7@main:
; Line 24
    xor eax, eax
; Line 25
    push    edx
    mov ecx, ebp
    push    eax
    lea edx, DWORD PTR $LN16@main
    call    @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8
    pop eax
    pop edx
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[ebp]
    xor ecx, ebp
    call    @__security_check_cookie@4
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
    npad    1
$LN16@main:
    DD  3
    DD  $LN15@main
$LN15@main:
    DD  -72                 ; ffffffb8H
    DD  64                  ; 00000040H
    DD  $LN12@main
    DD  -144                    ; ffffff70H
    DD  64                  ; 00000040H
    DD  $LN13@main
    DD  -216                    ; ffffff28H
    DD  64                  ; 00000040H
    DD  $LN14@main
$LN14@main:
    DB  114                 ; 00000072H
    DB  101                 ; 00000065H
    DB  115                 ; 00000073H
    DB  117                 ; 00000075H
    DB  108                 ; 0000006cH
    DB  116                 ; 00000074H
    DB  0
$LN13@main:
    DB  109                 ; 0000006dH
    DB  97                  ; 00000061H
    DB  116                 ; 00000074H
    DB  95                  ; 0000005fH
    DB  98                  ; 00000062H
    DB  0
$LN12@main:
    DB  109                 ; 0000006dH
    DB  97                  ; 00000061H
    DB  116                 ; 00000074H
    DB  95                  ; 0000005fH
    DB  97                  ; 00000061H
    DB  0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Comment: If it is a C code, why C++ tag instead of C?

Comment: *it is not the best code* are you sure? These days it's not exactly easy to outsmart compilers/compiler writers. Usually they know way more about the subject than you do, esp. when it comes to pipelining etc. Did you use the correct compiler flags?

Comment: C++ is derived from C. I'm writing this code in c++. This is .cpp file.

Comment: Also, why is this not the best code.

Comment: "I don't understand the assembly code" ... "it is not the best code" ... I don't understand how you can posit that it is not the best code if you don't even understand it... Chances of you being able to optimize the code by hand better than your compiler does are probably not as high as you might think...

Comment: That was compiler generated code. I wanted to optimize it, Am I not being clear.

Comment: The code seems definitely underoptimal. For example, mulss multiplies one pair at a moment; mulps could do it for 4 values at a time. But requiring this from a common target compiler seems improper. Why don't you find a library explicitly devoted to math computations?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: It is C++ code.  Microsoft doesn't have a useful C compiler (for modern definitions of useful).

Comment: @LaszloPapp: That's correct, [the Microsoft Optimizing C/C++ compiler is C90 and does not and never will support C99 or C11](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/)

Comment: C++ is derived from C but it's different. If you read many question about this you'll know why. Also, you need to try some optimizations to find out which is the best. You should check the [auto vectorization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/22/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-did-it-work.aspx) report too

Comment: The posted assembly looks like a _Debug_ build. Try looking at the output from an optimized _Release_ build instead.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Sure, it looks unoptimized... But a decent optimizer would turn this into `xor eax,eax; ret`. The `float result[]` is an **auto** variable, scoped to the function, and it is not read out inside the function. Since it goes *poof* when the function returns, everything may be optimized out.

Comment: @EOF: It's not that hard to prevent everything being optimized away. Just printing the result may be enough to prevent it. Note also the assembly listing shows the `/Od` (disable optimization) compiler flag was used.

Comment: @stijn, nonsense, compilers are still quite stupid.  It's easy to beat the compiler by knowing what your doing.  See my answer.

Comment: @twalberg, the most common implementation of matrix multiplication gets about 1% of the peak flops of the processor.  No compiler is going to optimize this for you.  The only way to do is to improve the implementation.  Compilers are stupid.

Comment: @Zboson I have a couple compilers here that would tend to disagree (`gcc`, `icc`, `clang`/`llvm`). Granted, they may not always produce 100% optimal code for every possible arrangement of statements, but in general they do a far better job optimizing than I could. There are rare occasions where I have actually turned to hand-tuned assembly in a tight inner loop for performance reasons, but that should be the exception. There's also something to be said about writing good code to begin with that the optimizer can do something with - a naive "most common implementation" is often bad code...

Comment: @twalberg, oh I think I understand the confusion.  I don't mean to imply that it's easy to optimize code better than the code you give it (hence why my answer only uses C/C++ with no intrinsics to get a 10 times speed up) but don't expect a compiler to do some magic to rewrite your code if you implementation is not very good.  Even if you choose the right algorithm (e.g. the one with the best time complexity) the compiler is unlikely to choose the best implementation.  You have to do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: you are actually wrong. Visual Studio 2013 does support C99.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: No it doesn't.  Try a simple program with C99 VLAs.  Or any of the other features in C99 that are not part of C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Apparently the distinction between "supports 4 features of C99" and "supports all of C99" is lost on you.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio and SSE is a red herring here (as well as the C++ vs. C nonsense).  Assuming you compile in Release mode there are other reason your code is inefficient especially for large matrices.  The main reason is that it's cache unfriendly.  To make your code efficient for an arbitrary n*n matrix you need optimize for big and small.

It's important to optimize for the cache BEFORE employing SIMD or threads.  In the code below I use block multiplication to speed up your code for a 1024x1204 matrix by more than a factor of ten (7.1 s with old code and 0.6s with new) using only a single thread without using SSE/AVX.  It's not going to do any good to use SIMD if your code is memory bound.

I have already described a first order improvement to matrix multiplication using the transpose here.
[OpenMP C++ Matrix Multiplication run slower in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634121/openmp-c-matrix-multiplication-run-slower-in-paralel/22637933#22637933)

But let me describe an even more cache friendly method.  Let's assume your hardware has two types of memory:

1. small and fast,
2. large and slow.

In reality, modern CPUs actually have several levels of this (L1 small and fast, L2 larger and slower, L3 even larger and slower, main memory even larger still and even slower still.  Some CPUs even have a L4) but this simple model with only two levels here will still lead to a big improvement in performance.

Using this model with two types of memory you can show that you will get the best performance by dividing your matrix into square tiles which fit in the small and fast memory and doing block matrix multiplication.  Next you want to rearrange the memory so that the elements of each tile are contiguous.

Below is some code showing how to do this.  I used a block size of 64x64 on a 1024x1024 matrix.  **It took 7s with your code and 0.65s with mine.** The matrix size has to be multiples of 64x64 but it's easy to extend this to an arbitrary size matrix.  If you want to see an example of how to optimize the blocks see this [Difference in performance between MSVC and GCC for highly optimized matrix multplication code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134279/difference-in-performance-between-msvc-and-gcc-for-highly-optimized-matrix-multp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

void reorder(float *a, float *b, int n, int bs) {
    int nb = n/bs;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<nb; j++) {
            for(int i2=0; i2<bs; i2++) {
                for(int j2=0; j2<bs; j2++) {
                    b[cnt++] = a[bs*(i*n+j) + i2*n + j2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void gemm_slow(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            float sum = c[i*n+j];
            for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {
                sum += a[i*n+k]*b[k*n+j];
            }
            c[i*n+j] += sum;
        }
    }
}

void gemm_block(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n, int n2) {
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n2; j++) {
            float sum = c[i*n+j];
            for(int k=0; k<n2; k++) {
                sum += a[i*n+k]*b[k*n2+j];
            }
            c[i*n+j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

void gemm(float *a, float*b, float*c, int n, int bs) {
    int nb = n/bs;
    float *b2 = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n);
    reorder(b,b2,n,bs);
    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<nb; j++) {   
            for(int k=0; k<nb; k++) {
                gemm_block(&a[bs*(i*n+k)],&b2[bs*bs*(k*nb+j)],&c[bs*(i*n+j)], n, bs);
            }
        }
    }
    free(b2);
}


int main() {
    const int bs = 64;
    const int n = 1024;
    float *a = new float[n*n];
    float *b = new float[n*n];
    float *c1 = new float[n*n]();
    float *c2 = new float[n*n]();
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++) {
        a[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
        b[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }
    double dtime;

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    gemm_slow(a,b,c1,n);
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("%f\n", dtime);

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    gemm(a,b,c2,n,64);
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("%f\n", dtime);

    printf("%d\n", memcmp(c1,c2, sizeof(float)*n*n));

}
```