# Improve OpenMP multi-threading parallel computing efficiency for matrix (multi-dimensional array) in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, multidimensional-array, openmp

I just started to use OpenMP to do parallel computing in C++. The program has a bad parallel performance. Since I don't know many multi-threading profiling tool (unlike simple gprof for single thread), I wrote a sample program to test the performance.

I have a 2D matrix(N * N), with each element a 3d vector(x, y, z). I simply do a double for loop to set each value in the matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    vectorStack[i][j] = VECTOR3D(1.0*i*i, 1.0*j*j, 1.0*i*j);
  }
}
```

where `VECTOR3D` is a simple class has `x, y, z` attributes:

```
class VECTOR3D {
    double x, y, z;                // component along each axis 
}
```

On the other hand, I can also use a (N * N * 3) 3D array to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    arrayHeap[i][j][0] = (1.0*i*i);
    arrayHeap[i][j][1] = (1.0*j*j);
    arrayHeap[i][j][2] = (1.0*i*j);
  }
}
```

From the memory aspect, there are also several different choices, such as use raw pointers with manually allocate and deallocate:

```
  double ***arrayHeap;
  arrayHeap = new double** [N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    arrayHeap[i] = new double* [N];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      arrayHeap[i][j] = new double[3];
    }
  }
```

or simply use `std::vector`:

```
  vector< vector<VECTOR3D>> vectorStack(N, vector<VECTOR3D>(N, VECTOR3D(0, 0, 0)));
```

I also considered to manually allocate continuous memory for arrays as did in [LAMMP(Molecular Simulation Package](http://lammps.sandia.gov) source code.

So my results for `N=10000` are listed here:

**For single thread:**

> OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out

Allocating memory for array on heap...

======= Array on heap Results =======

Finished within time (total): **0.720385** seconds

Finished within time (real): **0.720463** seconds

Deallocating memory for array on heap...

Allocating memory for array continous...

======= Array continuous Results =======

Finished within time (total): **0.819733** seconds

Finished within time (real): **0.819774** seconds

Deallocating memory for array continuous...

Allocating memory for vector on heap...

======= Vector on heap Results =======

Finished within time (total): **3.08715** seconds

Finished within time (real): **3.08725** seconds

Deallocating memory for vector on heap...

Allocating memory for vector on stack...

======= Vector on stack Results =======

Finished within time (total): **1.49888** seconds

Finished within time (real): **1.49895** seconds

**For multi-threads (threads=4):**

> OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out

Allocating memory for array on heap...

======= Array on heap Results =======

Finished within time (total): **2.29184** seconds

Finished within time (real): **0.577807** seconds

Deallocating memory for array on heap...

Allocating memory for array continous...

======= Array continuous Results =======

Finished within time (total): **1.79501** seconds

Finished within time (real): **0.454139** seconds

Deallocating memory for array continuous...

Allocating memory for vector on heap...

======= Vector on heap Results =======

Finished within time (total): **6.80917** seconds

Finished within time (real): **1.92541** seconds

Deallocating memory for vector on heap...

Allocating memory for vector on stack...

======= Vector on stack Results =======

Finished within time (total): **1.64086** seconds

Finished within time (real): **0.411** seconds

The overall parallel efficiency is not good. Unexpected, the fancy continuous memory allocating is not helpful?! Why is this happening? It seems the `std::vector` is good enough for this case?

Could someone explain the results for me? and I also need suggestions on how to improve the code.

Thanks very much!!!

**Attached all the source code.** 
(please directly go to main, there are several functions to manually manage the memory at the beginning).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cinttypes>
#include "vector3d.h"

typedef int64_t bigint;

void *smalloc(bigint nbytes, const char *name)
{
  if (nbytes == 0) return NULL;
  void *ptr = malloc(nbytes);
  return ptr;
}

template <typename TYPE>
TYPE ***create(TYPE ***&array, int n1, int n2, int n3, const char *name)
{
  bigint nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE)) * n1*n2*n3;
  TYPE *data = (TYPE *) smalloc(nbytes,name);
  nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE *)) * n1*n2;
  TYPE **plane = (TYPE **) smalloc(nbytes,name);
  nbytes = ((bigint) sizeof(TYPE **)) * n1;
  array = (TYPE ***) smalloc(nbytes,name);

  int i,j;
  bigint m;
  bigint n = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    m = ((bigint) i) * n2;
    array[i] = &plane[m];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
      plane[m+j] = &data[n];
      n += n3;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

template <typename TYPE>
TYPE ***create3d_offset(TYPE ***&array, int n1lo, int n1hi,
                        int n2, int n3, const char *name)
{
  int n1 = n1hi - n1lo + 1;
  create(array,n1,n2,n3,name);
  array -= n1lo;
  return array;
}

void sfree(void *ptr) {
  if (ptr == NULL) return;
  free(ptr);
}


template <typename TYPE>
void destroy(TYPE ***&array)
{
  if (array == NULL) return;
  sfree(array[0][0]);
  sfree(array[0]);
  sfree(array);
  array = NULL;
}

template <typename TYPE>
void destroy3d_offset(TYPE ***&array, int offset)
{
  if (array == NULL) return;
  sfree(&array[offset][0][0]);
  sfree(&array[offset][0]);
  sfree(&array[offset]);
  array = NULL;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  const int N = 10000;


  ///////////////////////////////////////

  double sum = 0.0;
  clock_t t;
  double startTime, stopTime, secsElapsed;


  printf("\n\nAllocating memory for array on heap...\n");
  double ***arrayHeap;
  arrayHeap = new double** [N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    arrayHeap[i] = new double* [N];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      arrayHeap[i][j] = new double[3];
    }
  }


  printf("======= Array on heap Results =======\n");

  sum = 0.0;
  t = clock();
  startTime = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
//#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
//#pragma omp for collapse(2)
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        arrayHeap[i][j][0] = (1.0*i*i);
        arrayHeap[i][j][1] = (1.0*j*j);
        arrayHeap[i][j][2] = (1.0*i*j);
      }
    }

  }

  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "Finished within time (total): " << ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
  stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
  secsElapsed = stopTime - startTime;
  cout << "Finished within time (real): " << secsElapsed << " seconds" << endl;

  printf("Deallocating memory for array on heap...\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      delete [] arrayHeap[i][j];
    }
    delete [] arrayHeap[i];
  }
  delete [] arrayHeap;


  ///////////////////////////////////////


  printf("\n\nAllocating memory for array continous...\n");
  double ***array_continuous;
  create3d_offset(array_continuous,0, N, N, 3, "array");

  printf("======= Array continuous Results =======\n");

  sum = 0.0;
  t = clock();
  startTime = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
//#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
//#pragma omp for collapse(2)
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        array_continuous[i][j][0] = (1.0*i*i);
        array_continuous[i][j][1] = (1.0*j*j);
        array_continuous[i][j][2] = (1.0*i*j);
      }
    }

  }

  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "Finished within time (total): " << ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
  stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
  secsElapsed = stopTime - startTime;
  cout << "Finished within time (real): " << secsElapsed << " seconds" << endl;


  printf("Deallocating memory for array continuous...\n");
  destroy3d_offset(array_continuous, 0);



///////////////////////////////////////k



  printf("\n\nAllocating memory for vector on heap...\n");
  VECTOR3D ***vectorHeap;
  vectorHeap = new VECTOR3D**[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    vectorHeap[i] = new VECTOR3D* [N];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      vectorHeap[i][j] = new VECTOR3D(0,0,0);
    }
  }

  printf("======= Vector on heap Results =======\n");
  sum = 0.0;
  t = clock();
  startTime = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
//#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
//#pragma omp for collapse(2)
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        vectorHeap[i][j] = new VECTOR3D(1.0*i*i, 1.0*j*j, 1.0*i*j);
      }
    }

  }

  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "Finished within time (total): " << ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
  stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
  secsElapsed = stopTime - startTime;
  cout << "Finished within time (real): " << secsElapsed << " seconds" << endl;

  printf("Deallocating memory for vector on heap...\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      delete [] vectorHeap[i][j];
    }
    delete [] vectorHeap[i];
  }
  delete [] vectorHeap;


  /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  printf("\n\nAllocating memory for vector on stack...\n");
  vector< vector<VECTOR3D>> vectorStack(N, vector<VECTOR3D>(N, VECTOR3D(0, 0, 0)));

  printf("======= Vector on stack Results =======\n");
  sum = 0.0;
  t = clock();
  startTime = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
  {
//#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
//#pragma omp for collapse(2)
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        vectorStack[i][j] = VECTOR3D(1.0*i*i, 1.0*j*j, 1.0*i*j);
      }
    }

  }

  t = clock() - t;
  cout << "Finished within time (total): " << ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
  stopTime = omp_get_wtime();
  secsElapsed = stopTime - startTime;
  cout << "Finished within time (real): " << secsElapsed << " seconds" << endl;


  /////////////////////////////////



  return 0;
}
```

And the `VECTOR3D` class:

```
#ifndef _VECTOR3D_H
#define _VECTOR3D_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

class VECTOR3D {
public:
  double x, y, z;                // component along each axis (cartesian)
  VECTOR3D(double xx = 0.0, double yy = 0.0, double zz = 0.0) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz)    // make a 3d vector
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## General Misconception

Your trivial loop is not compute bound, but entirely memory bound: You access each element only once. No re-use means that you cannot efficiently use caches. Therefore you can not expect a speedup equal to the number of used threads/cores. The actual speedup depends on the specific system (memory bandwidth).

## Indirection

All of your data structures, including the *fancy continuous memory* perform many indirections on the data access. This is not strictly necessary. To gain full advantage of the continuous memory, you should simply lay out your 2d array flat:

```
template<class T>
class Array2d
{
public:
    Array2d(size_t rows, size_t columns) : rows_(rows), columns_(columns), data_(rows_ * columns_) {}
    T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c)
    {
        return data_[r * columns_ + c];
    }

    const T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c) const
    {
        return data_[r * columns_ + c];
    }

private:
    size_t rows_;
    size_t columns_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

Note: You could also make a fancy `operator[]` that returns a proxy object providing another `operator[]` if you really must retain the `[i][j]` indexing.

## Clarification

If you are limited by memory bandwidth and N is large enough, there will be no noticeable performance difference between indirection or flat layout.

Comment: Thanks @Zulan for the clarification of memory bound and compute bound. Now the general question is: How to efficiently calculate a large matrix concerning the memory sharing. I guess the only answer is to make them continuous (given a fixed bandwidth). I'll try your data structure to see the performance.

Comment: As you suggested, I could also merge all the action of the matrix together. For example, I have N particles, in the `updatePosition` function, I need to calculate `r[i][j]`. Then in another `calculateForce` function, I use `r[i][j]` to calculate `force[i][j]`. I could merge them together in one function. However, it would be hard to maintain and change the program later since it's not a good design pattern. So there is a trade off there. I'll think about the design more.

Comment: I find there are very few open source multi-threading profiling tools there. Could you give me some suggestions? I'm using Linux/Unix.

Comment: I tested several cases, `Array2d<VECTOR3D> array2d(N, N)` from your code do not perform better :(

Comment: 1) I don't understand what you mean by *merge all the action of the matrix*. Are you referring to "array-of-structs vs. struct-of-arrays" kind of thing? If your actual code performs other operations on the matrix, I suggest clarifying your actual task (maybe in an additional question).

Comment: 2) There are actually a number of parallel performance analysis tools. [Here is a good overview](http://www.vi-hps.org/upload/material/general/ToolsGuide.pdf). [HPCToolkit](http://hpctoolkit.org/) is also useful.

Comment: 3) If you are limited by memory bandwidth and N is large enough, there will be no noticeable performance difference between indirection or flat layout.

Comment: Thanks for the great overview of tools. After reading lots of openmp stuff, I start to realize maybe it's a classical "false sharing" example. If the matrix has continuous memory, then every time an element changes, it pollutes the whole cache line, causing other threads waiting for the update. Maybe that's why the continuous memory is not a good idea, and it performs worse than indirections.